# Inquiry google game services for current matches

Tags: android, google-play-games

I'm implementing turn based game services for a simple game:
https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/turnbasedMultiplayer

I'm using the `GameHelper` class from basegameutils as recommended.

I want to save some data that isn't relevant (statistics) so I don't want to sent it between players. I'm saving this data locally (sqlite) linking it with `TurnBasedMatch.getMatchId()`.

What I need to know is how to inquiry google game services (I guess via `GameHelper`) which are the current matches for the signed player, so I can delete old local data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking better at documentation I finally found a solution for that.

If your activity extends from `BaseGameActivity` you can do the following:

```
Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.loadMatchesByStatus(getApiClient(),
            TurnBasedMatch.MATCH_TURN_STATUS_COMPLETE,                
            TurnBasedMatch.MATCH_TURN_STATUS_MY_TURN,
            TurnBasedMatch.MATCH_TURN_STATUS_THEIR_TURN)
            .setResultCallback(deleteNotPresentMatches);
```

using your own call back, for example:

```
private ResultCallback<TurnBasedMultiplayer.LoadMatchesResult> deleteNotPresentMatches = new ResultCallback<TurnBasedMultiplayer.LoadMatchesResult>() {
    public void onResult(TurnBasedMultiplayer.LoadMatchesResult r) { 
        //whatever you want, in my case delete local data for old matches
    }
};
```